# Как перегрузить методы манипулирования данными в адиминке django

Tags: django-admin, django

Доброго времени суток.
Как перегрузить методы манипулирования данными в адиминке django ─ например изменяю данные в одной таблице, информация об этом заносится в другую. 
Это нужно для синхронизации бд на сервере и мобильном клиенте, сам я пишу под android и до этого времени если нужен был сервер писал на php, захотелось попробовать реализовать тот же функционал на Django.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не очень понятное описание, но попробуйте почитать про [сигналы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/) - похоже, это то, что вам нужно. Админка тут ни при чем.

Comment: Спасибо ─ то что нужно )